# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException when try to validate using standart validator and xsd?

Tags: java, validation, xsd

There is Method threw 'org.xml.sax.SAXParseException' exception. when try to validate my data.
So, to validate my input data, I use javax.xml.validation standart package.

I hava xsd schema, that expected that there are 2 containers - Users and Error
Users can contain list of elements, in each sub-container, there is Value and objectId(not mandatory)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- edited with XMLSpy v2018 sp1 (x64 by Organization-->
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://mynamespace" targetNamespace="http://mynamespace" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <complexType name="User_Type">
        <sequence>
            <element name="objectId" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <annotation>
                    <documentation>(КМД)идентификатор риск-метрики, будет проигнорирован при операции добавления</documentation>
                </annotation>
                <simpleType>
                    <restriction base="string">
                        <maxLength value="36"/>
                    </restriction>
                </simpleType>
            </element>
            <element name="Value" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <simpleType>
                    <restriction base="string">
                        <maxLength value="1024"/>
                    </restriction>
                </simpleType>
            </element>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
    <complexType name="Message_Type">
        <sequence>
            <element name="Text" minOccurs="0">
                <simpleType>
                    <restriction base="string">
                        <maxLength value="2048"/>
                    </restriction>
                </simpleType>
            </element>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
    <element name="Users">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element name="User" type="tns:User_Type" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <element name="Error" type="tns:Message_Type" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </element>
</schema>
```

This input code I want to validate - there is only one user with  field.

```
String rm = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?><Users><User><Value>Value0</Value></User><Users>";
```

This code  - is a method. So, **rm** - is validate xml
**validationFile** contains link to xsd
And, I just read this file and try to valiate input stream of String

```
String rm = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?><Users><User><Value>Value0</Value></User><Users>";
String xmlFile = rm
String validationFile = "xsd/headVersions/users_1.8.xsd";

InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlFile.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
StreamSource source = new StreamSource(stream);

ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(validationFile).getFile());

SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
schemaFactory.newSchema(file).newValidator().validate(source);
return true;
```

And I have parse exception, that said in details, that

**cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'Users'.**

Answer (score 0):

In your .xsd I can see that you are using XMLSpy. 
Why don't you use it to validate your XML against the scheme?

Your XML is invalid because you are missing the Users end tag.
Following the corrected version:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Users>
  <User>
    <Value>Value0</Value>
  </User>
</Users>
```

I would suggest to fix your namespace problems in your scheme like following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- edited with XMLSpy v2018 sp1 (x64 by Organization-->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:complexType name="User_Type">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="objectId" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:maxLength value="36"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="Value" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:maxLength value="1024"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="Message_Type">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Text" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:maxLength value="2048"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="Users">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="User" type="User_Type" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xs:element name="Error" type="Message_Type" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I removed your documentation because it gives weird errors.
I used an online validator: https://www.liquid-technologies.com/online-xsd-validator